# Content div won't expand to 100% of its container

Tags: css, html, height

I have 2 divs: #container and #main-content, beneath them is a footer which needs to be out of sight even if the height of the content inside #main-content is smaller than body height.
Everything is fine when I have a lot of content, but when I have only a few lines of text only the #container div expands,#main-content doesn't.
I tried using 100% height for #main-content but it doesn't expand to its parent height.

html:

```
<div id="container" class="cf">
    <div id="main-content" role="main" class="cf">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h2><?php wp_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- #main-content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

css:

```
body { 
   width: auto; 
   height: 100%;
}

html {
   height: 100%;
}

#container {
   width: 1180px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: auto !important;
   min-height: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#main-content {
    background: white;
    width: 850px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you have to set min-height to main-content, because by default div never expand in height, div is block level element it expand 100% in width by default.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: can you show us your working code i mean website

Comment: Are you just trying to get a 100% height white background?

Comment: I'm using the second div to get a white background for main content and later I'm going to add a sidebar in #container which doesn't have white background

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove :

```
height: auto !important;
```

The !important erase your latter 100% style. 
A parent's Height must be set for a child 100% height to work.

Comment: if I do that #container doesn't expand

Comment: Strange, because it should work : http://jsfiddle.net/NneAU/ .Is container a child of body ?